# How to customize data using WordPress hooks in WP?

Tags: wordpress, hook

I have WordPress plugin that displays a recipe for food. I want to customize ingredients before displaying it. So I'm using the plugin hook to do this. I have create my separate plugin (`functions.php`) to customize the data before displaying. When I run the page I get ingredients `Array()` in my `customize_recipe_field($arg)` function and change ingredient using the ingredient name:

```
$arg[$key]['ingredient'] = $data['ingredient']."-Demo";` simply add "-Demo"
```

After that I print the `$arg` and I get the changes that are done by my plugin function, but when it displays on web page no changes are done. It still shows the old data.

Here is customize function:

```
function customize_recipe_field($arg) {
    foreach ($arg as $key=>$data){
        $arg[$key]['ingredient'] = $data['ingredient']."-Demo";
    }
    return $arg;
}
add_action('recipe_field_ingredients', 'customize_recipe_field');
```

Comment: Are you running `do_action()` somewhere?

Comment: no i not using do_action() in my functions.php. i write only one function [customize_recipe_field($arg)] for demo purpose.

Comment: I think you may want to use [`add_filter()` and `apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) instead...